# Obvious speedup to NSGA-II?

Tags: optimization

[Nondominated sorting genetic algorithm (NSGA) II](http://www.iitk.ac.in/kangal/Deb_NSGA-II.pdf) has become very well known for multiobjective optimization.  I'm starting to implement this, starting with the "fast-non-dominated-sort" function, i.e., not touching the anticrowding schemes just yet.  The pseudocode is show at the bottom of the 3rd page of the above NSGA II link.

Upon studying it, it seems to me (most likely naively!) that a simple speedup can be tweaked into the pseudocode.  Specifically, the testing of whether solution $q$ is nondominated can be brought outside of a nested loop.  More specifically, there are two nested loops, one to iterate $p$ over the solutions of the current nondominance front and another to iterate over each solution $q$ dominated by $p$.  The test of whether $q$ is nondominated for the *next* front is $n_q = 0$, where $n_q$ is the number of solutions that dominate solution $q$.  If we bring this outside the two nested loops, the test doesn't have to happen as often.  Yet it seems that $n_q$ should still have the correct value when both loops are done.  You would still have to iterate over all $q$'s to test them, but you wouldn't be visiting each one more than once.

Am I missing some obvious reason why the domination count is inside the nested loops?

Comment: You sure it is an appropriate place to ask this question?

Comment: Sorry if this is the wrong place.  From my googling, this seemed more appropriate than stackoverflow, which dealt with programming language-specific structures. If this is the wrong forum, I'd appreciate it if you could explain the mismatch and, if possible, suggest a more appropriate one.  Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the reasons for giving the algorithm as it is are (1) it is simpler and shorter, and (2) the overhead caused by the additional checks is negligible.

Comment: Hmmm, I can see that.  If you bring it outside the loop, you length the pseudocode to iterate over all the $q$'s once.

Comment: For those marking this question down, it would be helpful if you can explain why.  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't down-voted but I guess that those who have done so think this is not a _theoretical_ computer science question but a question about optimization of code (not algorithm) which would not be on-topic here, please see [help/on-topic] for more information about the scope. If for example you state the complexity before and after your suggested change then it might look more on-topic. For optimization of code probably [so] and [codereview.se] would be more suitable.

Comment: Ahhh.  I see.  I thought it belonged here because it dealt with an algorithm at the pseudocode level rather than the structures/features of an actual programming language.  But it is an practical implementation question rather than theoretical.  Thanks for pointing out the help page.  I will try stack overflow next time (hoping that they will not pan a question that is not language-specific)